# Does anyone know where I can find Winternals Recovery Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I know it has been acquired by Microsoft, but what is its name now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a page about this issue:

> [Microsoft Acquires Winternals (July
>   17, 2006)](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/winternals.mspx)
>
> Winternals offerings are no longer
>   available for purchase. However,
>   Microsoft is exploring **integrating
>   these technologies** into future
>   offerings. Technical support for
>   Winternals’ offerings will continue to
>   be available according to the terms of
>   customer agreements that have not been
>   terminated or modified, or on a paid
>   per incident basis.
>
> **Recovery Manager, Defrag Manager, Protection Manager:**
>
> The functionality and usage scenarios
>   of many of these products may be
>   addressed by Microsoft offerings.
>   Current Microsoft offerings can be
>   seen at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter.

So Winternals Recovery Manager is no longer available as a standalone product.

Comment: Thank you...Can you point me on a software that can help me access a dead win2003 because of a boo.ini issue ?

Comment: @Jonatan: If you want to access and recover your files, you can use a Live Linux CD. If you want to fix the `boot.ini` issue, you should ask this in a new question.

Comment: i think 1 then 2..

Comment: @Jonatan: See the answers to [this](http://superuser.com/q/219902/13567) question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/winternals.mspx) Recovery Manager is not longer avalible and has been absorbed into other products